# Page loads on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I've a template which i edited according to my needs. I've used jQuery for animations. The index page looks like this:

[image: index page]

Now if i navigate to another page suppose login and from that page if i click a link to my index page, the page spinner keeps spinning until i hit refresh.. Then the index page loads properly. Here is the image which of the page spinner which keeps spinning until i click refresh:

[image: page spinner]

The code goes something like this:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$('.page_spinner').fadeOut();
$('body').css({overflow:'auto', 'min-height':'800px'})
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Going through some suggestion i modified my code to :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.page_spinner').fadeOut();
$('body').css({overflow:'auto', 'min-height':'800px'})
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But then i get this:

[image: document]

Again on refresh this becomes proper. I've added all required jQuery links on my webpage. Also everything works fine on internet explorer. This happens in chrome. Any help appreciated. I guess the problem occurs only with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.page_spinner').fadeOut();
        $('body').css({overflow:'auto', 'min-height':'800px'})
    }, 1000);
});
```

***Note:*** This is a hackjob. See if it works!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the page looks like the 3rd image I've uploaded. Everything mixed and distorted. I'm not understanding why. Plus I'm googling from past 7 days on this distorted look on using **document.ready** but in vain

Comment: Is it possible to check out the page in live action?

Comment: I can upload it on jsfiddle but it wont display all the content i.e images, js, php.. But i can mail the code if its not a problem

Answer (score -1):

use meta tag: add this code inside the head of your page 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">

it will refresh the page automatically after 1s

[in this demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_attributes/meta/html5_meta_httpequiv_attribute.php) , the page automatically refreshes every 3 seconds and also loads a new page in its place